# How to turn off jump function Jquery tab

Tags: jquery, tabs

I found this code on the internet and everything is working fine. But I want to turn of the jumping function that jumps to a certain position on the webpage.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    // Hide all tab conten divs by default
    $(".tabContents").hide(); 

    // Show the first div of tab content by default
    $(".tabContents:first").show(); 

    //Fire the click event
    $("#tabContaier ul li a").click(function(){ 

        // Catch the click link
        var activeTab = $(this).attr("href"); 

        // Remove pre-highlighted link
        $("#tabContaier ul li a").removeClass("active"); 

        // set clicked link to highlight state
        $(this).addClass("active");         

        // hide currently visible tab content div
        $(".tabContents").hide(); 

        // show the target tab content div by matching clicked link.
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); 
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What "jumping function"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this function in my code:

```
function addToHistory(historyid)  {
    var nojump = $("<a>").attr("id", historyid);

    nojump.prependTo($("body", document));

    window.location.hash = historyid;

    nojump.remove();
}
```

That should make it so if a div's id is `#blah` and if the urls is `myUrl.com/#blah`, it will not just to `#blah` on the page when the hash is changed with this function.

Comment: Never mind i found the trick; I added return false; after // show the target tab content div by matching clicked link.
        $(activeTab).fadeIn();